Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows in Petrasim
I had used the Petrasim, and close this program make hs_xxxx.log file.
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000587bfb49, pid=12004, tid=0x000000000000293c
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_172-b11) (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.172-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
Problematic frame:
C  0x00000000587bfb49
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
I searched to solve a error. but Not looking for it

If you don't need that exact version, remove it and install the latest

The error is not failing to write a mini dump but the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. Are you having a programming error? Where is the code?
